# value sharing between two components angular2

Tags: angular, components, angular2-routing, angular-components

I am working on angular 2 application with open layer map. in that i need to share the location coordinate from one components to other components.

one components

```
placesChanged() {
    var places = this.searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places == null) return;
    if (places == undefined) return;
    if (places.length == 0) return;

    this.searchResultsSource.clear();

    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    places.forEach(this.processPlace.bind(this));

    // if the drawn result(s) is only one
    if (this.searchResultsSource.getFeatures().length == 1) {
        var singleFeature = this.searchResultsSource.getFeatures()[0];
        this.pos = singleFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        console.log(this.pos);
    }
    this.animateView(places.length);

}
```

in this i am getting the pos value as geocoordinate 
and i want to share that pos value to other components.

other components

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<BufferDialogComponent>,public searchcomponent: SearchComponent) {console.log(this.searchcomponent.pos);}
```

on pos i am getting error undefined.
please help me.

Comment: Is there any parent child relationship between these two components?

Comment: @TheDictator No !!

Comment: If you console inside constructor, obviously it will show you undefined, because that was executed before your service had that value.

Move your console to some other function and check.

Comment: @AmitChigadani i tried , but still it showing undefined..!